# Can I remove amp from the URL on AMP

Tags: google-analytics, amp

When discussing implementing AMP throughout the site our conversion rate optimisation department weren't too happy because of how this may affect their analytics and usability tools.

Is it possible to remove the amp from the URL and still have AMP or does Google need this to know which pages to cache?